# Find the max value in a column based on header name

Tags: excel

I need to find the max value in a column based on the header name. For example, I have a table that is ever changing because it is based on a query. On a cell in a separate worksheet, I need the value to be the max value of a particular column.

Right now I have a Column in the table named J0152. I need to find the max value in this column.

I have tried using the match function to get the column number but I don't know how to convert a column number into a range (column 2 into B:B).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look into using R1C1 notation. A highly underestimated aspect of excel. It nakes life so much easier when dealing with column numbers.

Comment: See for example: https://www.google.nl/amp/s/excelchamps.com/blog/r1c1-reference-style/amp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`MATCH` for this.

Working example below. I don't know what your actual data is obviously but I created this basic example. The formula in cell `H4` looks up the max value in the column name which is in cell `G4`.

```
= MAX(INDEX($A$2:$E$6,0,MATCH(G4,$A$1:$E$1,0)))
```

[image]

If necessary, you can replace the limited column references with full column references, e.g. replace `$A$2:$E$6` with `$A:$E`.

Comment: This worked great! I use index/match for a lot of things but haven't seen it used in a situation like this. This will be a good tool for me to add. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, `INDEX(<range>,0,<column>)` returns the full column number in `<range>` and `INDEX(<range>,<row>,0)` returns the full row number in `<range>`. This comes in really handy for situations like this where the range for some other opaterion (e.g. `MAX`) is dynamic.